# Slide (toggle) divs to one side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created similar layout to the one I am trying to achieve on my webpage. Please look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U7dhB/). I would like to slide(toggle) to the left all the `<div class="slide"></div>` by clicking on `<div class="clickMe"></div>`. I have seen a lot of similar question, but so far I have not been succesful.

**Edit.**
My question is probably misleading. I am looking for something like jQuery functions `slideUp(), slideDown(), slideToggle()` but such that the content would slide sideways e.g. `slideLeft()`. So far I have found, that nothing like that exists.

**Update**
So I have come to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/U7dhB/2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to `.slide { }`

```
position: relative;
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I would like to hide it to a side without pushing it totally of the screen? And be able to show it back? Like some sort of side menu.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to set global variable that hold state to be able to show `.slide` again as follows:

```
state = true;
$('.clickMe').click(function(){
    if (state){    
    $( ".slide" ).animate({ "left": "-=500px" }, "slow" );
        state = false;
    }
    else{
        $( ".slide" ).animate({ "left": "" }, "slow" );
        state = true;
    }

});
```

Checkout this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U7dhB/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but I have probably mislead you all by adding the `animate()`. Image the divs in a middle of page, I don't want it to ride over everything on the page. I simple want to hide it to one side (not side of a window). Something like slideUp/Down/Toggle(), but slideLeft/Right(). I think nothing like that exists, so that;s why I have used animate().